# Corrupted data from the camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm having some issues with a particular device (BQ Aquaris M5 - Android 5.0.2) which returns some  data from the onPictureTaken() camera callback. The colors are completely messed up:

[image]

This has never happened before and I've tested in several devices already without any issues.

Things that I've already seen/tried:

- Using the back camera instead of the front camera, displays the image correctly.
- The SurfaceView displays the image correctly.
- Increasing the delay between the photo is taken and the camera is opened (We had an issue before that made the image blurry, and running the takePicture within a PostDelayed of several hundreds of ms solved the issue).
- Data from the callback is already corrupted. Image is displayed as a icon marker in a GMaps Activity passed (after resized) as a bundle extra for a new intent.

  ```
  final byte[] photo = b.getByteArray("photo");
  Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lon)));

  if (photo!=null){
      final Bitmap bmpPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photo, 0, photo.length);
      marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmpPhoto));            
  }
  ```